# Homepage Rich Snippet Star Ratings not showing in Google SERP

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, schema.org, homepage

I have added [Schema Aggregate Rating Reviews](https://schema.org/AggregateRating) to my site and I can confirm that [Google's Rich Snippet Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) has no issues with my code. After waiting some time Google has enabled review stars on all pages apart from the home page.

*Using Google's Site Search Command: `site:http://www.example.com` reveals:*

[image: Google Search results for 'site:soapboxdesign.co.uk': the first result is the homepage, without any Rich Snippet; the other results show a Rich Snippet with rating stars]

Question:

- How do I enable rich snippets on the homepage so Google displays review stars using Schema Aggregate Rating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Search doesn’t seem to support Rich Snippets for homepages.

This is currently not documented, but [confirmed by the Google employee @methode (on SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616800/1591669):

> We (Google) don't accept rich snippets for homepages; rich snippet annotations should be placed on leaf pages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's explains why it's not displaying, then!

Comment: Is this guideline still valid, that Google doesn't support rich results for homepages?

Comment: @Sanchit: No idea, as it wasn’t published in the first place. If a certain feature is not supported on homepages, I would hope that their documentation would state that by now. FWIW, their [general guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#structured-data-guidelines) don’t mention such an restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Unor is absolutely right that Google does not return Aggregate Rating Review Stars on the home page. It should be noted that multiple language sites using sub folders will have review stars returned into the search results because `/en/`, `/de/` and so on are not the home pages. If they automatically redirect then they become the homepage. Using a 301 redirect to `/home/`, `/start/` or anything else will not make reveal stars display on the homepage.

Review Stars on Google My Business

It possible to return review stars in the sidebar of Google using [Google My Business](https://www.google.com/business/). Adding your business to Google My Business will allow you to obtain reviews on your business and these can help your local rankings and improve confidence on your brands and services. You will need a minimal of 5 reviews for them to appear and they look something like this:

[image: Google My Business BYBE in Bournemouth]

Answer (score 0):

Some companies go around this by setting their homepage url when you enter to /us, /ca, /en - this way it shows the page rating without it being the "home page".

From what I understand it is also allowed to do this by using review partner like Trustpilot, but rating will show only on Google Ads.