# Not able to see structered data in search results even when it looks fine in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool

My website uses structured data schema. It is showing up correctly in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool. It still is not showing in search results.

Why is that and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

When you have uploaded the structure data on your website, as usually structure data will take time to show in search results.

Comment: How much time?    Do you have experience with this?   Is there documentation?

Comment: yeah i have implemented structure data for a website last month and its started showing in search after 10-15 days. But hard to give any time estimation, its all depend upon how structured data is marked up

Comment: can you give example of that implementation. I found time-date and pricing data in table ( <table>) shown more frequently.

Answer (score 2):

This can have various reasons.

- **It can take time.** From their [Rich Snippets documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/):

  > Google will discover it the next time we crawl your site (although it may take some time for rich snippets to appear in search results).
- **It depends on a "variety of signals".** From their [Rich Snippets documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/):

  > When our algorithms discover technically correct markup on a page, we use a variety of signals to determine when to show rich snippets, including compliance with our [Webmaster Quality Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769) and [Structured Data Policies](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies). As a result, correctly marked up content may not always trigger rich snippet in our search results.

  (For example, the Sitelinks Search Box [will only be shown for navigational queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35104027/1591669).)
- **It might not meet their [quality guidelines](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies#quality_guidelines)** (not misleading/deceptive, up-to-date, accurate) and **it might not meet their relevancy standards**:

  > High-quality structured data must not create a misleading or deceptive experience for search users. It should be an up-to-date and accurate reflection of the topic and content already found on the page, such as text, images, and videos.
  >
  > […]
  >
  > We perform algorithmic and manual quality checks to ensure that structured data meets relevancy standards. In cases where we see structured data that does not comply with these standards, we reserve the right to take manual action (e.g., disable rich snippets for a site) in order to maintain a high-quality search experience for our users.
- **It might not meet their [guidelines about hidden content](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies#non-visible_content_and_machine-readable_alternative)**:

  > In other words, you generally shouldn't mark up content that is not visible to users.
  >
  > […]
  >
  > The `meta` tag should not be used to hide content that is not visible to users in any form, since it might create misleading or deceptive search experience.
- **It might not comply with the [policies](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies#policies_specific_to_each_type_of_structured_data) for a specific Rich Snippet**:

  > In addition to the guidelines above, each type of structured data can have specific technical and quality guidelines.
- For Knowledge Graph features (i.e., not Rich Snippets), **your site might not be the authority**. From their [Structured Data overview](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/):

  > If you're the authority for certain content, Google can treat the structured data on your site as factual and import it into the Knowledge Graph
- For Rich Snippets (i.e., not Knowledge Graph features), **you might expect it for your homepage**, but Google [doesn’t seem to show Rich Snippets for homepages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/87540/17633).
- **You might be using a syntax not yet supported.** For example, JSON-LD is not supported for all features ([example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/84372/17633)), but recommended for others ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34245691/1591669)).
- **The Google Structured Data Testing Tool might have a bug** ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31145753/1591669)).