# How can I get product prices to appear in Google reviews using rich snippets in WooCommerce?

Tags: seo, wordpress, rich-snippets, woocommerce

I am looking to have the product prices appear as part of the product description on Google via Rich Snippets.

Currently, if someone reviews any of my products, the average rating shows up in the Rich snippet area (grey between the blue title/link and the description (black)).

The fact the rating is showing up is leading me to believe that Rich Snippets is already activated/encorporated.

I was wondering if someone could help me show the price of the product alongside the rating?

I have done a lot of googling and found that WooCommerce supports schema.org by default and am keen to know if anyone can help me activate it?

I have checked my pages using Googles Structured Data Testing Tool and all the required schema is present. However, it doesn't show up on a search.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the code you're using so users can see if there's something missing or needed.

Comment: @dan I am not using any specific code. I am using the default settings from Woocommerce. I have tested using the Google Structured data Testing Tool and apparently all relevant information is there with the Schema.org structure but it doesnt display in the search results.

Comment: In the right-side of the Structured Data Testing Tool under "Detected" you should see the Item. Click on that and copy the code pertaining to it on the left-side in the HTML starting with `"@context": "http://schema.org"` You should note that Google decides what it thinks should be displayed and that structured data are just [clues](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) for it to selectively use.

Comment: See also: [Not able to see structered data in search results even when it looks fine in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89645/not-able-to-see-structered-data-in-search-results-even-when-it-looks-fine-in-the)

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to be able to answer this, so it's being put on hold until you add the code discussed above.

Comment: @dan I can't add code to the question if I do not have any code. I have used a wordpress plugin which send to work for some products and not others

Comment: I provided directions above on how you can provide the code, plugins like every web application simply generate HTML, CSS, or JavaScript  source code that can be viewed in a browser (right-click "View page source"), or in this case is visible in the Structured Data Testing Tool.  It should really only take a few minutes to copy that into the question.