# Review Schemas not showing for home page

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

Hope you all having a wonderful day and crunching some SEO. I am trying to get review schema appear for my client's website. The schema has been implemented correctly (tested using data structure tool) and as a result of this reviews/ratings (stars) are showing for every other pages but home page.
What can I do to get the ratings show for the home page?

Have a blessed one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not display internal Schema reviews on home pages within any type of search due to abuse. The only review stars that can appear in search results is a local search and the reviews must be on Google My Business and must have over 5 reviews.

Comment: Thanks for your input Simon. If that's the case then how are these guys pulling this off? https://kiteboardschool.nl/en/

Comment: Because `/en/` is not the homepage. Their homepage is `https://kiteboardschool.nl/` which does not return any review stars. Do a [**site:https://kiteboardschool.nl/**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=site:https:%2F%2Fkiteboardschool.nl%2F). If your site is multi-region then you can do similar, or focus more efforts into the services pages and have those rank higher. You can only get local review stars within the sidebar of Google on home pages, see: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87537/homepage-rich-snippet-star-ratings-not-showing-in-google-serp